Plotting a sequence and its series using tikz
i've been trying to plot a geometric sequence and its sum up to the term plotted at the same time using tikz. I've got a valid result, however I'd like to know if it's there a way to plot the summation without having to use a closed expression for the partial sums. Thank you! 
This is my code:
\begin{center}
\resizebox{15cm}{7cm}{%
 
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    width=15cm,
    height=9cm,
    domain = 0:15,
    samples = 15,
    xlabel = \(n\),
    xmin=0, xmax=16,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.25,
    xtick={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15},
    ytick={0.5,1},
]

\addplot[only marks,domain=1:15,
    red,
    color=red
    ]
    {(0.5)^x};
    \addlegendentry{$x_n$};

\addplot[only marks, mark=square, domain=1:15,
blue,]{\RepeatFunction{1}{x}{}};\addlegendentry{$S_n$};

\addplot[violet]{1};



   \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
 }

\end{center}



Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

The computation ability of TikZ/LaTeX is quite limited. You may have a look this Asymptote way https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/640401/140722

Welcome to TeX.SX! Where does the command \RepeatFunction come from?

Still you did not give MWE? https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

This is without using closed expression for the partial sums and with Asymptote code ^^

// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
usepackage("amsmath");
unitsize(1cm,5cm);
size(8cm);
import graph;
import math;  // for partialsum 
int n=16;
real[] a; a[0]=0;
for(int i=1; i<n; ++i) a[i]=1/(2*i);

// points of the sequence and its partial sum
real[] A=partialsum(a);
pair[] pointsA,pointsa;  
for(int i=1; i<A.length; ++i){ 
    pointsA.push((i,A[i]));
    pointsa.push((i,a[i]));
}

// joining by straight segments
path pH=operator--(...pointsA);
path pA=operator--(...pointsa);

draw(Label("$A_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_k$",align=3N+3W,EndPoint,red),pH,gray+.2pt);

draw(Label("$a_k=\dfrac{1}{2^k}$",align=3N+3W,EndPoint,blue),pA,gray+.2pt);


// decoration axes
for (int i : new int[]{1,5,10,15}){
label(string(i),(i,0),2S);
draw((i,0)--(i,-.1),gray);
}

for (real i : new real[]{0.5,1,1.5,2}){
label(string(i),(0,i),2W);
draw((0,i)--(-.2,i),gray);
}

xaxis(Label("$x$",align=2NE),Arrow(TeXHead));
yaxis(Label("$y$",align=2W),Arrow(TeXHead));
draw((1,1/2)--(1,0)^^(1,1/2)--(0,1/2),dashed+gray);

dot(pointsA,red);
dot(pointsa,blue);
dot(pointsa[0],blue+red);

shipout(bbox(5mm,invisible));


and how should I implement this to the rest of the document?

you can directly use Asymptote code in .tex file (so you need to install Asymptote, then properly config something), see https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/doc/LaTeX-usage.html There is another way: run the code on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ then download pdf file of the figure, and use \includegraphics in your LaTeX document
